# Clean up iTunes excess

Tags: itunes, mac

Over the past years, I have removed plenty of songs from my iTunes library, but not deleted the files, and now my Music/iTunes folder is double the size of what iTunes reports as my library size. I don't care about any of the songs I have removed from my library. Is there any way to delete all of them? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There's a handy AppleScript that will identify files in your iTunes folder that aren't in the iTunes library: [Music Folder Files Not Added](http://dougscripts.com/466).

Download the file, open the .dmg and add the script file to `~/Library/iTunes/Scripts` (you may need to create that folder if it's not there already). Then it should appear under the script menu in iTunes (a scroll icon between the *Window* and *Help* menus).